# Pass data from action script to javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

Does anyone know if I can pass data from flash (action script) to java script? If yes... how?

(I need to send an ajax request with a text typed inside a textbox from actionscript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ExternalInterface to interact w/ JavaScript

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(){ 
      ExternalInterface.call("myFunc", "param");
});
```

for some reason i run into issues if i declare JavaScript tag `type='text/javascript'`. so i recommend using:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function myFunc(myparam){
      //your code
}
</script>
```

Comment: That will probably work, but I believe the official way to use it is ExternalInterface.call("myFunc", "param") - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()

Comment: +1 @Lars yes sir, you are correct.  will make changes in my own code and on here =D thanks. do u know why it won't work when i use `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` ?