# how to pass value from java script to embedded flex object?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, dom, externalinterface

I am trying to figure how to pass string value(url) from html form to embedded flex object.
the only method i found so far is "addCallback" method described in http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_5.html
In the example i used flex function "myFunc(s:String)" is registered with "ExternalInterface" and called later from javascript

### --->mySwf.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- wrapper/AddCallbackExample.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="initApp()">
  <mx:Script>
     import flash.external.*;
      import mx.controls.Alert;
     public function initApp():void {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFlexFunction",myFunc);
     }  
     public function myFunc(s:String):void {

         Alert.show(s, 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);
     }

  </mx:Script>
  <mx:Button id="myButton" 
        label="FLEX BUTTON" 
        click="Alert.show('FLEX LOADED!', 'Alert Box', mx.controls.Alert.OK);"/>
  <mx:Label id="l1"/>

</mx:Application>
```

---

### external.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function callApp() {

        mySwf.myFlexFunction("show me something");
    }
</SCRIPT>


<form id="f1">
    <button onClick="callApp()">HTML BUTTON</button>
</form>

<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
WIDTH="850"
HEIGHT="610"
CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0">
<EMBED SRC="mySwf.swf"
WIDTH="850"
HEIGHT="610"
PLAY="true" 
LOOP="true"
QUALITY="high" 
scale="noborder"
PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"> 
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
</html>
```

The method doesn't seem to be working at all. If I push Flex button - i can see Flex popup dialog. When I push HTML button, calling myFunc in Flex via ExternalInterface - nothing
happens... Any pointers to errors in my code?
Thank you,

Comment: You should always format your code as code, especially because XML tags will not be shown otherwise.  Use the {} button or indent 4 spaces.  I did it for you this time.

Comment: which browser are you testing it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in case you aren't using the right browser:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    // This function returns the appropriate reference, 
    // depending on the browser.
    function getFlexApp(appName)
    {
      if (navigator.appName.indexOf ("Microsoft") !=-1)
      {
        return window[appName];
      } 
      else 
      {
        return document[appName];
      }
    }

    function callApp() {
        getFlexApp('mySwf').myFunc("show me something");
    }

</SCRIPT>
```

also you did not give an id to your object which is how the DOM identifies

```
<OBJECT id='mySwf' CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
```

try this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunc",myFunc);
```

Comment: please take a look at the answer. you did not attach id='mySwf' on the Object

Comment: Tried everything you suggested - no difference so far.

Comment: Can you suggest other methods to do it ( pass arg from html to flex)?

Comment: Try see if you can setup this tutorial http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

Comment: from error console: Error: getFlexApp("mySwf").myFlexFunction is not a function

Comment: is this error while you compile the flex or is this error from browser?

Comment: name the flex function the same as your call back function, and change `getFlexApp('mySwf').myFunc("show me something");` in your JavaScript

Comment: done - same problem: Error: getFlexApp("mySwf").myFunc is not a function
Source File: file:///home/myhome/FLEX/samples/video/external1.html
Line: 5

Comment: i am not sure what the true issue is but i would recommand going through this tutorial and see if that works for you as well http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

Comment: try to put the getFlexApp function on top of the callApp() in your javascript but that shouldn't effect it.

Comment: Flex sample doesn't work either. It seems as ExternalInterface methods supported on Windows and Mac. I am testing on Linux and Solaris. Can that be a problem?

Comment: @user270398 that is very strange.  it shouldn't matter because its browser based, but are you compiling flex through wine? here, try this simple Flash to JavaScript communication and see if this works.  I don't know man.  I've tried my best to help you =( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017970/javascript-flash-pass-data-from-action-script-to-javascript/5018005#5018005